# Completely off-topic, promoting!

Tags: discussion, scope, spam-handling

In the past hour, I have seen two off-topic question promoting a service. Both were marked as spam. I am not even on that much, so if there is two this hour, and there is on average one a hour, 24 a day??? They aren't even technology related! It is annoying, but how can we stop it? All suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's always spam around this time. Bots or people make new accounts and paste the stuff in. We have a bot in the AU chatroom that notifies us when something trips it.

If it's spam, we all flag it as spam and it goes away pretty quickly. If a mod is in the room and/or sees the post on the main site, they'll be able to delete it right away,

We can't really prevent it without maybe adding some sort of captcha, and those can be annoying (even the "I'm not a robot" checboxes). The best thing to do is flag any posts you see like that as spam and downvote.